# Wouldn't MD5 encrypting be reverse engineering by computing once and for all the hash of every string?

Tags: security, md5

I was reading about MD5 encrypting with java. And I was wondering how it can be safe while you can just compute once and for all the hash of every possible string. That would sure take a bit of time but once it's done you can just store all the  couples inside a database table, and search for any hashcode in this table quite fast... right?

What am i missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: While waiting for an actual answer to appear, I suggest taking a look at the Wikipedia entry for Rainbow Tables (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table).

Comment: Can you post a list of every possible string to help us answer?

Comment: Thanks levi, interesting article.

Comment: md5 is a message digest function it is in no way shape or form an method of encryption.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MD5 generates 2^128 possible values, so you need at least 2^128 strings hashed for complete coverage. Hashing 2^32 strings every second (which is A LOT) you will need 79228162514264337593543950336 seconds, which is 2512308552583217199186 years.

Personally, I do not expect to last so long. And it's quite possible that the universe will not too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer blaze, but since we are considering passwords, most of the time it will be between like 5 and 12 caracters (of course some of longer but most of them is less than 12 I gess), and the set of possible caracter used is way less than like 100 different caracters. So it must give something in the range of the 100^12 string to hash, to cover the vast majority of passwords. Which seems easily computable right?

Comment: Any sane security solution do hash passwords with salt, which gives you say 8 extra random characters and 50^8 = 2^47 multiplier for time and storage required.

Comment: I've never used a password shorter than 12 characters. Neither should you.

Comment: not to mention that it would take up quite some diskspace (0.50×10^15 yottabyte).